# MySQL - Not using Index

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I'm trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong.  This query doesn't seem to be using the index, as its taking way to long.

When executing:

```
Explain SELECT a, b, c, d  FROM `table` WHERE d = 4013456

id       select_type     table       type    possible_keys       key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra`
1      SIMPLE          table       ALL     d                   NULL    NULL     NULL    79787   Using where`
index:
d    INDEX       79787
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? the query inside the explain is taking 10 seconds.. seems as if it should take less than a second.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtablename;` ?

Comment: is d a string or number?

Comment: When i try, it shows me a small snippet of the create table exec, i don't think the option for (full debug?) is turned on for my server.

Comment: FYI: If your table has only a small number of rows, the query optimizer can sometimes decide not to use an index because a full table scan would be quicker. Does your table have a smallish number of rows?

Comment: Chaos-> Thanks for info on partitioning, Will use this as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your index is not being used is because `d` is a `varchar` (you mentioned this in a comment) and you have an integer in your where clause. If you change your query to:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d  FROM `table` WHERE d = '4013456';
```

it will be more likely to use an index. But a better solution might be to change the column to an integer and leave the query alone (if that's possible given your other circumstances).

Comment: it's okay, you would be surprised how often I run into this.  Many programmers are unaware of the consequences of opting out of the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

If d is a varchar, you need to put it in quotes.  Leaving the quotes out will not use the index properly.